# Problems getting SQLBindParameter to work in C++

Tags: visual-c++, odbc

I downloaded a small sample program in C++ that opens an ODBC connection to SQL Server, issues a query, and prints the result.

When the query string includes a parameter and I call SQLBindParameter, the query execution returns SQL_SUCCESS but subsequentally fails to get any records.

If I do the equivalent query directly in SQL Management studio it works.

Here's the code. Note that to keep things **short** I have removed error checking in places where I've not been having problems. The real connection string is obfuscated.

```
SQLHANDLE sqlenvhandle = 0;    
SQLHANDLE sqlconnectionhandle = 0;
SQLHANDLE sqlstatementhandle = 0;
SQLHANDLE sqlstatementhandle2 = 0;
SQLRETURN retcode = 0;
SQLWCHAR retconstring[1024];

retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlenvhandle);
retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlenvhandle,SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlenvhandle, &sqlconnectionhandle);
retcode = SQLDriverConnect(sqlconnectionhandle, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)_T("--connectionstring--"),
                            SQL_NTS, retconstring, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnectionhandle, &sqlstatementhandle2);

SQLWCHAR *query = _T("SELECT * FROM gbm_models WHERE stagename like ?");
SQLWCHAR *searchname = _T("Yuk%\0");

retcode = SQLPrepare (sqlstatementhandle2, query, SQL_NTS);
SQLINTEGER xxx = SQL_NTS;
retcode = SQLBindParameter( sqlstatementhandle2, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR,
                            SQL_VARCHAR, 5, 0, searchname, 0, &xxx );

SQLWCHAR sqlbuffer[400];
SQLINTEGER buflen = 0;

retcode = SQLExecute (sqlstatementhandle2);

char name[512];
int id;

while(SQLFetch(sqlstatementhandle2) == SQL_SUCCESS)
{
    SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle2, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &id, 0, NULL);
    SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle2, 4, SQL_C_CHAR, name, 500, NULL);
    cout << id << " " << name << endl;
}

SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle2 );
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle );
SQLDisconnect(sqlconnectionhandle);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlenvhandle);
```

None of these calls return an error. What happens is that the call to **SQLFetch** returns SQL_NO_DATA.  If I replace the "?" in the initial query string with the actual name string, and comment out the **SQLBindParameter** call, it works fine and retrieves the expected data.  So obviously, the search string is not making its way into the query correctly.

Any ideas what's wrong?  Does anybody know a way to get the **processed** query string with the parameter substitution done? I thought the **SQLNativeSql** function did that, but when I call it, I just get back the original query, so I'm not sure if it's working right or what. Could it be a Unicode thing?

Comment: "get the **processed** query string with the parameter substitution done" - you are confused. SQL data binding has absolutely nothing to do with the "parameter substitution". As for your actual question - sorry, I don't have enough information. Maybe look at the DB server logs to see what is being executed and with what parameters?

Comment: Just noticed... `SQLWCHAR *searchname` yet when you bind you specify the data type as `SQL_C_CHAR`. Are those two types even compatible?

Comment: @yephlck - Thanks for responding. Maybe I was not clear, but i'm not confused about what binding the parameter does. I was just wondering if there was a way to see a version of the query after parameter substitution was done. It would help in debugging. I did look at server logs and they showed the query without the parameter substitution. That's why I suspect a problem with SQLBindParameter even though there's no error. As to the question about SQLWCHAR and SQL_C_CHAR, I dunno. That's kind of why I'm asking questions here. The compiler throws errors on using SQLCHAR instead.

Comment: When using a binding you **never** see an "expanded" SQL, it just doesn't exist by design

Comment: I understand that an expanded SQL query string is not part of the normal process, but given how useful one could be in debugging, I did not want to dismiss the possibility. I know it would have helped me zero in on this problem more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the datatypes at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714556(v=vs.85).aspx

`SQL_C_CHAR` is not compatible with the `SQLWCHAR` so your binding fails to do a proper job - it is using a pointer to double-byte wide characters and a resulting "C-string" is not what you'd expect it to be.

Use compatible datatypes, in your case just go with:

```
SQLCHAR *searchname = "Yuk%";
```

Comment: Using SQLCHAR makes the compiler throw an error on SQLPrepare, which is mapped to SQLPrepareW when using Unicode. I am increasingly sure that the problem is wrapped around specifying the right data types

Comment: Figured it out... Used SQLWCHAR for the query string to make SQLPrepare happy, so used SQL_WVARCHAR for the _ParameterType_ value, thinking it had to match the query string.  Then I tried setting the _ValueType_ parameter SQL_C_CHAR for a non-Unicode string, or SQL_C_WCHAR for a Unicode string, and either worked OK.

Comment: Indeed, as long as you use compatible datatypes you should be fine

Comment: The Unicode stuff is not very well documented, and the data type constants aren't even defined in the same place. Annoying.